# Unity3d, Spotlight doesn't work correctly all the time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, light

There is a problem (most likely with Post Processing) when light hits objects, it illuminates a larger area than itself (as in 1 picture), but at the same moment it works normally in scene viewer (2 picture) and when paused, you can observe this problem.
How can I fix this problem so the light will render as it is on second picture?

[image: 1 picture]
[image: 2 picture]

If you increase the intensity of lighting, then it will work. Can it also be done at a lower intensity?

Comment: Hm not sure if this is related to post processing.. the first image looks like it is treated as point light for some reason

Comment: I noticed that this is due to Spotlight highlighting first one and then another terrain texture. But I do not know how to fix it